# What are the implications of not being independently and identically distributed?

Tags: iid

In my basic statistics course we always assume that the sample observations are iid. I get why they would be iid (eg. in the case of a coin toss) and I also intuitively get that if they are not iid then the observations we get would probably have some bias or inaccuracies but is it possible to mathematically prove that?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: likelihood of data

Answer (score 7):

Consider an urn with 3 red balls and 4 green balls. The experiment consists of drawing two balls in succession from the urn, with 
all balls in the urn
being equally likely to be chosen. Let $X$ be a Bernoulli random
variable that has value $1$ if and only if the
first ball drawn is red, and $Y$ a Bernoulli random variable
that has value $1$ if and only if the second ball 
drawn is red.

**Sampling with replacement:** Suppose that the experimenter draws one ball from the urn, notes its color, returns the ball to the urn, *shakes
well* (this is to ensure that the ball just tossed back in is not sitting
on top of the pile and so very likely to be drawn again), and then
draws a second ball.

It is easy to determine that $P(X=1) = P(Y=1) = \frac 37$, that
is, $X$ and $Y$ are *identically distributed* and it is also
easy to verify that $X$ and $Y$ are *independent identically
distributed* random variables.

**Sampling without replacement:** The first draw is as described
above but after the color of the first ball has been noted, the
ball *is not returned to the urn* (so the urn now has only six
balls in it), and (after shaking well again) the second ball is
drawn. Clearly $P(X=1) = \frac 37$ as before. But, what freaks
beginning students out is that $P(Y=1)$ *also* equals $\frac 37$ !!
Note that the experiment has $7\times 6 = 42$ outcomes instead
of $49$ outcomes in the sampling with replacement described above,
but if you make a list of all $42$ outcomes, $18$ of them are of
the form $(\star_i, R_i)$  where $R_i$ is the $i$-tj red ball,
$i = 1,2,3,$ while $\star_i$ is any ball *other* than $R_i$.
So $$P(Y=1) = P(\text{second ball red}) = \frac{18}{42}=\frac 37$$ as claimed.  Thus, $X$ and $Y$ are **identically distributed**
random variables, but they are **not independent** random variables.
Note that 
$$P(X=1, Y=1) = P((R_i,R_j)) = \frac{6}{42} = \frac 17
\neq P(X=1)P(Y=1).$$

As an example of random variables that are independent but
not identically distributed, let $Z=1-Y$ be a Bernoulli
random variable that has value $1$ if and only if the second
ball is green.  In sampling with replacement, it is easily verified
that $X$ and $Z$ are *independent but not identically distributed*
while in sampling without replacement, $X$ and $Z$ are *neither
independent nor identically distributed.*

---

In short, whether or not the `iid` assumption is valid totally,
or in part (the `i` but not the `id` or *vice versa*)
, or not at all (neither the `i` nor the `id`) is something
that depends on how the experiment is carried out. This is
not something that can be proved *mathematically;* rather
it is an issue of *modeling*, how we translate the grubby
facts of coins that have been tossed so often that it is
hard to distinguish Heads from Tails, and unshaken urns 
that nobody told us about, into mathematical symbols and
notations where we can apply a purely intellectual
approach.